# Vue component inside legacy php/jquery project

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, vue.js, nuxt.js

I've got this big legacy web app based on Codeigniter and jQuery.

The plan is to phase out jQuery and start using Vuejs instead. We are replacing certain parts of the website step by step.

I have just installed Nuxtjs and got the file structure the way i like it inside the legacy project.

Now to the question. How can i access a Vue component from one of my legacy javascript files?

App.vue

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js + TypeScript App" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";

export default Vue.extend({
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
});
</script>
```

main.ts

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import store from "./store";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

I want to display my App.vue inside an ordinary php/html view.

Comment: You say you're using Nuxt.js.. is this because you're intending to replace the back-end of your app too? Or your intention is just to swap out all the jQuery for Vue?

Comment: We are not going to replace the backend. We are building a new external API tho which we are going to call from the vue parts. So Vue is not going to communicate with our legacy backend.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing something similar right now, the project was originally written using Thymeleaf and jQuery and now we are switching to Vue.

You can communicate between vue components and non-vue components in a few ways, none of them are "pretty".

## Communication

### Classic JavaScript events

Pretty straightforward

```js
// legacy code
document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('legacy-vue.something-happened', { detail: payload }))

// vue component
created () {
  document.addEventListener('legacy-vue.something-happened', this.onSomethingHappened)
},

destroyed () { // don't forget to remove the listener!
  document.removeEventListener('legacy-vue.something-happened', this.onSomethingHappened)
}
```

### Exposing EventHub

Similar to the previous one, but you are using vue events instead. **This is what i would recommend**, because it's the Vue way of handling events and your goal is to vuetify your app.

```js
// initialization
const hub = new Vue()

Vue.prototype.$eventHub = hub
window.$vueEventHub = hub

// legacy code
$vueEventHub.$emit('something-happened', payload)

// vue component
created () {
  this.$eventHub.$on('something-happened', this.onSomethingHappened)
},

destroyed () {
  this.$eventHub.$off('something-happened', this.onSomethingHappened)
}
```

### Exposing whole components

The most flexible way, but it's hard to see what's going on where. Event based approaches the lesser evil in my opinion (it's easy to track events).

```js
// vue component
created () {
  window.vueTableComponent = this
}

// legacy component
vueTableComponent.fetchNextPage()
vueTableComponent.registerOnPageFetchedCallback(callback);
```

## Summary

No matter which approach you pick, i recommend doing something like this:

Let's say that you have TableComponent. TableComponent has few props like apiUrl, emits `row-clicked` event, etc. It would be best to design the component without thinking about your legacy code at all, and then create it's legacy wrapper because at one point it will be used both with vue-only screens and with mixed-screens (with both legacy components and vue components). An example:

**LegacyTableComponentWrapper.vue**

```html
<template>
  <table-component
    :api-path="apiPath"
    @row-clicked="onRowClicked"
    ref="table-component"
  />
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    apiPath: null
  }),

  methods: {
    onRowClicked (row) {
      this.$eventHub.$emit('table-row-clicked', row) // notify legacy code
    },

    onApiPathDefined (payload) {
      this.apiPath = payload
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    // legacy code might require the TableComponent to act differently
    // and if you don't want the TableComponent to know whenever it's legacy or not
    // you can always override one or more of it's methods.
    this.$refs['table-component'] = this.overriddenImplementationOfXYZ
  },

  created () {
    this.$eventHub.$on('define-api-path', this.onApiPathDefined)
  },

  destroyed () {
    this.$eventHub.$off('define-api-path', this.onApiPathDefined)
  }
}
```

It's sure more work at first, but will save you a headache later, when you will be working on your first view which is fully in vue and all that legacy communication stuff is in the way.

Comment: First of, thanks a lot for a thoroughly answer. I might have been a but unclear, but we are not going to communicate directly with out legacy backend but via a new API we are building. So what i have to do is pretty much only to display my index.vue in a php view/bind ot to a element via jQuery. Any ideas?

Comment: Ops. To instantiate vue you only need to create div with specific id (lets say - `app`), import scripts and css generated by vue, and then in the index of your vue project create new vue instance the standard way - `new Vue({ el: '#app', ... })`. No further changes necessary. Im still not sure if i understood correctly, is this what you were asking for?

Comment: Im not sure i understand fully. My Vue "project" is created inside its own folder of the legacy project. What am i going to import in the legacy file? 

Right now in the Vue part of the application i have App.vue, main.ts and a HelloWorld.vue component.

I want to show the App.vue in my legacy file.

I am going to update the original post. please look there for a mor thorough explanation.

Comment: The wrapper div in your App component's template (`<div id="app">`) shouldn't be there. When your JS bundle is run in the browser, the new Vue instance that is created will look for an element in the current page with an ID of 'app' and attach itself there. Your App component will be rendered there, replacing whatever is inside of that element.

Comment: I still dont really get it. I removed the the "app" div and created a div with an ID in the file i want to present the component. What more do i have to do in that file? Because Vue cant find the element.